# can you add a value to a postgresql 11 partition list

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I want to use list partitioning to partition a large table representing service orders based on the value of the customer id column.   When a new customer is added to the system, I would like to be able to add that customer to the list of values related to an existing partition.  I would think there would be a relatively easy/quick way to do this since no existing rows need be moved. Essentially it seems like changing (maybe by dropping and adding) a constraint on a child table. But I have not been able to find a reference in the documentation to way to accomplish this. I am currently using aws rds with postgresql version 11.5 but could potentially update.

Answer (score 0):

Using list partitioning requires you to explicitly create each partition and state the corresponding value. You can therefore create a new table for the new customer_id with the same structure as the parent table and then use

```
ATTACH PARTITION partition_name { FOR VALUES partition_bound_spec | DEFAULT }
```

Or, if you have a lot of customers and don't want to end up with many partitions and/or don't wish to create tables on the go, you can use hash partitioning on the customer_id column. That way, you can predefine the number of partitions you want and new customers will simply be added to one of them (according to the result of the Postgresql's hash function.